# Using <vector> with cin and for() loop C++

Tags: c++

I have this piece of code from my exercise in which I need to:

- Add a student with his name, id, education level and 3 grades
- Modify a grade of a student
- Delete a student
- Show a list of approved students
- Show a list of repproved students
- Show a full list

So I have done this using vectors and here is my code:

```
int resp = 0;

vector<int> ids;
vector<string> names;
vector<string> levels;
vector<double> grades1;
vector<double> grades2;
vector<double> grades3;
vector<double> average;
vector<double> approved;
vector<double> repproved;

string name, level;
int id, elim, id_delete, i=0;
double grade=0, sum=0;

do {

    cout<<"######### OPTIONS MENU #########"<<"\n\n";

    cout<<"[1] Add a student"<<"\n";
    cout<<"[2] Add grades of a student"<<"\n";
    cout<<"[3] Modify grades of a student"<<"\n";   
    cout<<"[4] Delete a student"<<"\n";
    cout<<"[5] Show approved list"<<"\n";
    cout<<"[6] Show repproved list"<<"\n";
    cout<<"[7] Show the full list"<<"\n";
    cout<<"[8] Exit"<<"\n\n";

    cin>>resp;

    switch(resp) {
        case 1:
            cout<<"Enter the student's name: \n";
            cin.sync(); cin.clear();
            getline(cin, name);
            names.push_back(name);
            cout<<"Enter the student's id: \n";
            cin>>id;
            ids.push_back(id);
            cout<<"Enter the student's school level: \n";
            cin.sync(); cin.clear();
            getline(cin, level);
            levels.push_back(level);

            cout<<"Student added";

        break;
        case 2:
            cout<<"Enter the grade 1 of the student: \n";
            cin>>grade;
            grades1.push_back(grade);
            cout<<"Enter the grade 2 of the student: \n";
            cin>>grade;
            grades2.push_back(grade);
            cout<<"Enter the grade 3 of the student: \n";
            cin>>grade;
            grades3.push_back(grade);

            cout<<"Grades added";
        break;
        case 3:
            cout<<"Enter the student's id you wish to modify grades on: \n";
            cin>>id_delete;

            for(int i=0; i<ids.size(); i++) {
                if(id_delete==ids[i]) {
                    id_delete = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            i=id_delete;
            cout<<"Enter the new grade 1 of the student: \n";
            cin>>grade;
            grades1[i] = grade;

            cout<<"Enter the new grade 2 of the student: \n";
            cin>>grade;
            grades2[i] = grade;

            cout<<"Enter the new grade 3 of the student: \n";
            cin>>grade;
            grades3[i] = grade;

            cout<<"Grades modified\n";

        break;
        case 4:
            cout<<"Enter the student's id you wish delete: \n";
            cin>>id_delete;

            for(int i=0; i<ids.size(); i++) {
                if(id_delete==ids[i]) {
                    id_delete = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            ids.erase (ids.begin()+(id_delete-1));
            names.erase (names.begin()+(id_delete-1));
            levels.erase (levels.begin()+(id_delete-1));
            grades1.erase (grades1.begin()+(id_delete-1));
            grades2.erase (grades2.begin()+(id_delete-1));
            grades3.erase (grades3.begin()+(id_delete-1));

            cout<<"Student deleted\n";

        break;
        case 5:
            for(i = 0; i<ids.size(); i++) {
                average[i] = (grades1[i] + grades2[i] + grades3[i])/3;
            }

            for(i = 0; i<ids.size(); i++) {
                if(average[i] >= 7 && average[i] <= 10) {
                    approved[i] = average[i];
                } else {
                        repproved[i] = average[i];
                    }

            }

            for(i = 0; i<ids.size(); i++) {
                cout<<approved[i]<<endl;
            }
        break;
        case 6:
            for(i = 0; i<ids.size(); i++) {
                cout<<repproved[i]<<endl;
            }
        break;
        case 7:
            for(i = 0; i<ids.size(); i++) {
                cout<<approved[i]<<endl;
            }

            for(i = 0; i<ids.size(); i++) {
                cout<<repproved[i]<<endl;
            }
```

But it throws "exercise.exe has stopped working" when selecting options 5, 6 and 7.

PS. I'm a beginner in C++ and it is my first programming language, sadly...

Comment: Paste the whole code. Do you know how to debug? What have you tried so far.

Comment: When I type in 5, the very first thing your program does after that is `average[0] = (grades1[0] + grades2[0] + grades3[0])/3;`, but `average` is empty, so there is no `average[0]`.

Comment: pastebin the whole code: http://pastebin.com/FcAkhjY1

Comment: You variables called `i` at multiple scopes. You should consider renaming the variable declared here `int id, elim, id_delete, i=0;`, as something else.

Comment: Off topic recommendation: unless you have a good reason not to that I can't see , make a structure that unifies name, level, grade, etc... and have 1 vector made up of the structure. Eg: `struct student {int id; std::string name; std::string level; double grade1; ...}` and `std::vector<student> students;` Should really simplify your book-keeping.

Answer (score 0):

The crash occurs because you access members of several vectors beyond their ends.

For example:

```
for(i = 0; i<ids.size(); i++) {
    average[i] = (grades1[i] + grades2[i] + grades3[i])/3;
}
```

You never expand the average array before accessing it.  You do expand the grades arrays, but only in response to specific user input.

You probably want to add entries in all the arrays each time a student is added.  And you should ask for the student ID before adding the grades, and treat that case just like modify.

A better design would be to use a map from student ID to a structure.

Answer (score 0):

AS the vectors

```
vector<double> average;
vector<double> approved;
vector<double> repproved;
```

are created ,thier size is 0 i.e they do not contain any elements,so when you are accessing the elements of the above vectors as average[i] for the first time ,which is not in memory ,so you have to first insert the average as,

```
average.push_back((grades1[i] + grades2[i] + grades3[i])/3);
```

not as

```
average[i] = (grades1[i] + grades2[i] + grades3[i])/3;
```

and same with the other two vectors

> approved and 
>   reapproved

I hope you are clear.